# Nodejs how to put multiple id's into an if

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

When I try to put multiple id's into an if it only registers the first one.

```js
if (message.author.id != '196568585202565121' || '110324497353052160') return message.reply("You don't have the perms")
```

It will only reply to the first id and not the second one. The second one will get the mssage you don't have the perms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order return message if non of the id's match, do this:

```
  if (message.author.id !== '196568585202565121' || message.author.id !== '110324497353052160') {
      return message.reply("You don't have the perms");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (message.author.id != '196568585202565121' || '110324497353052160') return message.reply("You don't have the perms")
```

This states: 
If the message author's ID is not 196568585202565121 or 110324497353052160.
What you want it to say is:
if the message author's ID is not 196568585202565121 or if the message author's ID is not 196568585202565121.

Change up your line to:

```
if (message.author.id !== '196568585202565121' || message.author.id !== '110324497353052160')
```

Also notice that the != was replaced with a double equal. !==. In JavaScript, != is not strict enough. We need to use !==

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the comparison in both parts of the if like this:

```
if (message.author.id !== '196568585202565121' || message.author.id !== '110324497353052160') return message.reply("You don't have the perms")
```

You could also add the ids to an array and filter the array.

```
let arr = ['196568585202565121', '110324497353052160']

let filter = arr.filter ( e => e === message.author.id)

arr.length > 0 return message.reply("You don't have the perms")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array with `.includes()` method.

```
if(!['196568585202565121','110324497353052160'].includes(message.author.id)) {
  // to the things...
}
```

Read more: [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)